# How to read RGB data sent to USB keyboard with Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, arduino, usb

I have an RGB LED strip hooked to an Arduino Uno and I want to sync that LED strip to the effects currently sent from Razer Synapse to my keyboard/mouse on Windows 10.

Since Razer Synapse only sends RGB data to their hardware and 3rd party hardware (NZXT, Corsair, etc) my other options are to either snoop the RAM for the RGB data that is sent to the devices, or snoop the USB data sent by Synapse to the devices so I don't have to process animations since all will be done by Synapse.

I've tried to use [Device Monitoring Studio](https://www.hhdsoftware.com/device-monitoring-studio) to read USB data and I did manage to find what I wanted but I am not sure what kind of data that is and how to get the same data into Python programatically.

[image: description of device monitoring studio data]

I've tried to use [pywinusb](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb) and the [raw_data.py](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/blob/master/examples/raw_data.py) example to read raw data from the keyboard itself but I don't get anything. Maybe I'm not using the proper library for my task.

How do I get that (assuming binary) data with Python to send it via serial to my Arduino ?

Comment: Perhaps replace Razer Synapse with a self-made tool that sends RGB data to both your Arduino and the Razer hardware, after reverse engineering their protocol with device monitoring studio.

Comment: I wouldn't need to reverse engineer their protocol since you have APIs available for making your own apps that talk to Razer gear. The lack of APIs is for reading data already generated by the OEM app.

Comment: Yeah the idea was to generate the data yourself instead of relying on the OEM app.